# How do I find if the object ball I track crosses a line that I have drawn?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am using c++ with OpenCV 3.0 to create a basic form of SimulCam.

I am currently stuck on finding a way to check when the object ball has crossed/intersected with a line that I have drawn on the output window.

The ball is being tracked using contours, and ultimately I would like to work out the exact frame number this intersect happens at.

But first, I would like to understand how to perform the check to see when the Object ball has crossed/intersected with the drawn line.

[Scene with ball moving towards line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTT32.png)

I have the contours for the object, I would like to understand how to perform the check of an intersection.

**Code for finding contours and Object Tracking:**

```
findContours(resizedThresh, contourVector, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

contourVector.resize(contourVector.size());

line(resizedF_Fast, Point(300, 0), Point(300, 360), Scalar(255), 2, 8);
for (size_t i = 0; i < contourVector.size(); i++) {

     approxPolyDP(Mat(contourVector[i]), contourVector[i], 0.01*arcLength(contourVector[i], true), true);
     double area = contourArea(contourVector[i]);

     if (contourVector[i].size() > 5 && (area > 200)) {
        ++circlesC;
        drawContours(resizedF_Fast, contourVector, i, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2, CV_AA, hierarchy, abs(1));
        searchForMovement(resizedThresh, resizedF_Fast);
     }
}
```

---

I have done some other research, and I have been looking into using *lineIterator*, but i'm not entirely sure..

Apologies for the potential crude code, novice here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is your line defined ? Is it always vertical or it can be anything ?

Comment: In this case, the line is always vertical. Further down the line, it would change to be an extracted feature from a frame, i.e. a start finish line in the scenery etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked through this, i'll post the general idea here.

For each frame, calculate the object contours.

- each contour will have an x and y coordinate stored

Used *LineIterator* (e.g. lineIt) to cycle through all values of a line.

```
if (xpos_contour < lineIt.pos().x) {
     // Object is on the left of the line
}
else if (xpos_contour > lineIt.pos().x) {
     // Object is to the right of the line
}
```

Bear in mind the input video im using filmed top down, so only the x coordinate mattered.

Answer (score 0):

My first approach would be to fit a circle into your contour points and then compute the distance between the line and your circle center with the dot product. Maybe like this (didnt tried it out):

```
Point Pc; // circle center
Point L0(300,0);
Point L1(300,360);

double v[] = {L1.x-L0.x,L1.y-L0.y};
double w[] = {Pc.x-L0.x,Pc.y-L0.y};

Mat v(1,2,CV_32F,v);
Mat w(1,2,CV_32F,w);

double c1 = w.dot(v);
double c2 = v.dot(v);  
double b = c1 / c2;

Mat Pb = L0 + b * v;
double distance = norm(Pc,Pb);
```

Then you check if your distance minus your circle radius is less equal zero.

But due to perspective transformation of your camera the ball becomes an ellipse and my assumption becomes less accurate.

If you need a more accurate solution you need to check every contour point and take the minimum distance.

[This link](http://geomalgorithms.com/a02-_lines.html) shows some code and further explanations.